# Getting ValueError: y contains new labels when using scikit learn's LabelEncoder

Tags: python, machine-learning, encoding, scikit-learn, categorical-data

I have a series like:

```
df['ID'] = ['ABC123', 'IDF345', ...]
```

I'm using scikit's `LabelEncoder` to convert it to numerical values to be fed into the `RandomForestClassifier`.

During the training, I'm doing as follows:

```
le_id = LabelEncoder()
df['ID'] = le_id.fit_transform(df.ID)
```

But, now for testing/prediction, when I pass in new data, I want to transform the 'ID' from this data based on `le_id` i.e., if same values are present then transform it according to the above label encoder, otherwise assign a new numerical value.

In the test file, I was doing as follows:

```
new_df['ID'] = le_dpid.transform(new_df.ID)
```

But, I'm getting the following error: `ValueError: y contains new labels`

How do I fix this?? Thanks!

UPDATE:

So the task I have is to use the below (for example) as training data and predict the `'High', 'Mod', 'Low'` values for new BankNum, ID combinations. The model should learn the characteristics where a 'High' is given, where a 'Low' is given from the training dataset. For example, below a 'High' is given when there are multiple entries with same BankNum and different IDs.

```
df = 

BankNum   | ID    | Labels

0098-7772 | AB123 | High
0098-7772 | ED245 | High
0098-7772 | ED343 | High
0870-7771 | ED200 | Mod
0870-7771 | ED100 | Mod
0098-2123 | GH564 | Low
```

And then predict it on something like:

```
BankNum   |  ID | 

00982222  | AB999 | 
00982222  | AB999 |
00981111  | AB890 |
```

I'm doing something like this:

```
df['BankNum'] = df.BankNum.astype(np.float128)

    le_id = LabelEncoder()
    df['ID'] = le_id.fit_transform(df.ID)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[['BankNum', 'ID'], df.Labels, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
    clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42, n_estimators=140)
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 10):

I think the error message is very clear: Your test dataset contains `ID` labels which have not been included in your training data set. For this items, the `LabelEncoder` can not find a suitable numeric value to represent. There are a few ways to solve this problem. You can either try to balance your data set, so that you are sure that each label is not only present in your test but also in your training data. Otherwise, you can try to follow one of the ideas presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057621/sklearn-labelencoder-with-never-seen-before-values).

One of the possibles solutions is, that you search through your data set at the beginning, get a list of all unique `ID` values, train the `LabelEncoder` on this list, and keep the rest of your code just as it is at the moment.

An other possible solution is, to check that the test data have only labels which have been seen in the training process. If there is a new label, you have to set it to some fallback value like `unknown_id` (or something like this). Doin this, you put all new, unknown `ID`s in one class; for this items the prediction will then fail, but you can use the rest of your code as it is now.

Comment: Please read the update in my question, I've added what I'm trying to do. I need the model to be able to predict on new values of ID based on what characteristics it learned from the training data. If I keep them as unknown_id then the whole purpose will fail.

Answer (score 4):

you can try solution from "sklearn.LabelEncoder with never seen before values" https://stackoverflow.com/a/48169252/9043549
The thing is to create dictionary with classes, than map column and fill new classes with some "known value"

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
suf="_le"
col="a"
df[col+suf] = le.fit_transform(df[col])
dic = dict(zip(le.classes_, le.transform(le.classes_)))
col='b'
df[col+suf]=df[col].map(dic).fillna(dic["c"]).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data are `pd.DataFrame` I suggest you this simple solution...

I build a custom transformer that integer maps each categorical feature. When fitted you can transform all the data you want. You can compute also simple label encoding or onehot encoding.

**If new unseen categories or NaNs are present in new data:**

**1]** For label encoding, 0 is a special token reserved for mapping these cases.

**2]** For onehot encoding, all the onehot columns are zeros in these cases.

```
class FeatureTransformer:
    
    def __init__(self, categorical_features):
        self.categorical_features = categorical_features
        
    def fit(self, X):

        if not isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame):
            raise ValueError("Pass a pandas.DataFrame")
            
        if not isinstance(self.categorical_features, list):
            raise ValueError(
                "Pass categorical_features as a list of column names")
                    
        self.encoding = {}
        for c in self.categorical_features:

            _, int_id = X[c].factorize()
            self.encoding[c] = dict(zip(list(int_id), range(1,len(int_id)+1)))
            
        return self

    def transform(self, X, onehot=True):

        if not isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame):
            raise ValueError("Pass a pandas.DataFrame")

        if not hasattr(self, 'encoding'):
            raise AttributeError("FeatureTransformer must be fitted")
            
        df = X.drop(self.categorical_features, axis=1)
        
        if onehot:  # one-hot encoding
            for c in sorted(self.categorical_features):            
                categories = X[c].map(self.encoding[c]).values
                for val in self.encoding[c].values():
                    df["{}_{}".format(c,val)] = (categories == val).astype('int16')
        else:       # label encoding
            for c in sorted(self.categorical_features):
                df[c] = X[c].map(self.encoding[c]).fillna(0)
            
        return df
```

Usage:

```
X_train = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,20, (100,10)))
X_test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(20,30, (100,10)))

ft = FeatureTransformer(categorical_features=[0,1,3])
ft.fit(X_train)

ft.transform(X_test, onehot=False).shape
```

Answer (score 1):

This is in fact a known bug on LabelEncoder : [BUG for fit_transform](https://github.com/rapidsai/cuml/issues/2451) ... basically you have to fit it and then transform. It will work fine ! A suggestion is to keep a dictionary of your encoders to each and every column so that in the inverse transform you are able to retrieve the original categorical values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to mentally process operations better when dealing in `DataFrames`. The approach below fits and transforms the `LabelEncoder()` using the training data, then uses a series of `pd.merge` joins to map the trained fit/transform encoder values to the test data. When there is a test data value not seen in the training data, the code defaults to the max trained encoder value + 1.

```
# encode class values as integers
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y_train)
encoded_y_train = encoder.transform(y_train)

# make a dataframe of the unique train values and their corresponding encoded integers
y_map = pd.DataFrame({'y_train': y_train, 'encoded_y_train': encoded_y_train})
y_map = y_map.drop_duplicates()

# map the unique test values to the trained encoded integers
y_test_df = pd.DataFrame({'y_test': y_test})
y_test_unique = y_test_df.drop_duplicates()
y_join = pd.merge(y_test_unique, y_map, 
                  left_on = 'y_test', right_on = 'y_train', 
                  how = 'left')

# if the test category is not found in the training category group, then make the 
# value the maximum value of the training group + 1                  
y_join['encoded_y_test'] = np.where(y_join['encoded_y_train'].isnull(), 
                                    y_map.shape[0] + 1, 
                                    y_join['encoded_y_train']).astype('int')

encoded_y_test = pd.merge(y_test_df, y_join, on = 'y_test', how = 'left') \
    .encoded_y_test.values
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy hack around this issue.

Assuming X is the dataframe of features,

1. First, we need to create a list of dicts which would have the key as the iterable starting from 0 and the corresponding value pair would be the categorical column name. We easily accomplish this using enum.

   `cat_cols_enum = list(enumerate(X.select_dtypes(include = ['O']).columns))`
2. Then the idea is to create a list of label encoders whose dimension is equal to the number of qualitative(categorical) columns present in the dataframe X.

   `le = [LabelEncoder() for i in range(len(cat_cols_enum))]`
3. Next and the last part would be fitting each of the label encoders present in the list of encoders with the unique values of each of the categorical columns present in the list of dicts respectively.

   `for i in cat_cols_enum: le[i[0]].fit(X[i[1]].value_counts().index)`

Now, we can transform the labels to their respective encodings using

```
for i in cat_cols_enum:
X[i[1]] = le[i[0]].transform(X[i[1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when `transform` function getting any new value for which `LabelEncoder` try to encode and because in training samples, when you are using `fit_transform`, that specific value did not present in the corpus. So there is a hack, whether use all the unique values with `fit_transform` function if you are sure that no new value will come further, or try some different encoding method which suits on the problem statement like `HashingEncoder`.

Here is the example if no further new values will come in testing

```
le_id.fit_transform(list(set(df['ID'].unique()).union(set(new_df['ID'].unique())))) 
new_df['ID'] = le_id.transform(new_df.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue. I understand that you have to do encoding for each column and save pickle file for each technically.

As you are aware LabelEncoder() works on single column at a time. Suppose you applied fit_transform on each column in loop and created a pickle file.

It would only remember fit from last column not for others.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps someone as it's more recent.

sklearn uses the fit_transform to perform the fit function and transform function directing on label encoding.
To solve the problem for Y label throwing error for unseen values, use:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()     
le.fit_transform(Col)
```

This solves it!

Comment: Nop it does not solve it ! The problem here is with the inverse transform ... and I am doing exactly your suggestion and getting the same error posted here... unfortunately.

Answer (score -4):

I used

```
       le.fit_transform(Col)
```

and I was able to resolve the issue. It does fit and transform both. we dont need to worry about unknown values in the test split