# Pandas' get_dummies due to this problem of unseen data

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am facing the issue with ValueError: y contains new labels: xxxx. And I found the solution here: [sklearn.LabelEncoder with never seen before values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057621/sklearn-labelencoder-with-never-seen-before-values/48169252#48169252). But I am not sure how to convert the sklearn to pd.get_dummies?

This is my code

```
    import json
import itertools
import os

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer, LabelEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

    from tensorflow import keras
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
    from keras.preprocessing import text, sequence
    from keras import utils

    # The CSV was generated from this query: 
    data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
    data.head()

    # Confirm that we have a balanced dataset
    # Note: data was randomly shuffled in our BigQuery query
    data['tags'].value_counts()

    # Split data into train and test
    train_size = int(len(data) * .8)
    print ("Train size: %d" % train_size)
    print ("Test size: %d" % (len(data) - train_size))

    train_posts = data['post'][:train_size]
    train_tags = data['tags'][:train_size]


    test_posts = data['post'][train_size:]
    test_tags = data['tags'][train_size:]

    max_words = 1000
    tokenize = text.Tokenizer(num_words=max_words, char_level=False)

    tokenize.fit_on_texts(train_posts) # only fit on train
    x_train = tokenize.texts_to_matrix(train_posts)
    x_test = tokenize.texts_to_matrix(test_posts)

    dictionary = tokenize.word_index
    with open('dictionary.json', 'w') as dictionary_file:
        json.dump(dictionary, dictionary_file)


    # Use sklearn utility to convert label strings to numbered index
    encoder = LabelEncoder()
    encoder.fit(train_tags.fillna('0'))

    y_train = encoder.transform(train_tags.fillna('0'))
    y_test = encoder.transform(test_tags.fillna('0'))

    # Converts the labels to a one-hot representation
    num_classes = np.max(y_train) + 1
    y_train = utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
    y_test = utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
```

And here is my dummy data:

```
post,tags
Congenital Adrenal Hyperplasia: Calcium Channels as Therapeutic Targets,Hyperplasia
Does Lead Burden Alter Neuropsychological Development?,Myopia
41.8 Degree Centigrade Whole Body Hyperthermia for the Treatment of Rheumatoid Diseases,Rheumatic Diseases
Body Water Content in Cyanotic Congenital Heart Disease,Heart Diseases
Effects of Training Intensity on the CHD Risk Factors in Postmenopausal Women,Cardiovascular Diseases
Intraoral Grafting of Ex Vivo Produced Oral Mucosal Composites,Mouth Diseases
Prevalence of Carbohydrate Intolerance in Lean and Obese Children,Glucose Intolerance
Correction of Myopia Evaluation Trial (COMET),Myopia
Randomized Trial of Vitamin A and Vitamin E Supplementation for Retinitis Pigmentosa,Retinitis
```

Comment: What is  `utils`? Could you include your import statements?

Comment: i updated the code above: from keras import utils