# how to get the labelencoder for new data in Decision Tree

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, decision-tree, label-encoding

I'm performing the Decision Tree with the help of below sample data.

[image]

So I've converted the above data to LabelEncoder to perform Decision Tree and successfully created a DT model.

[image]

So now my requirement is I would like to predict on the below values, So how to pass these values in the python code.

[image]

In order to predict the existing value I can use the below Predict Code.

```
model.predict([[2,1,1]])
```

**COMPLETE CODE**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r"salaries.csv")
df.head()

inputs = df.drop('salary_more_then_100k',axis='columns')
target = df['salary_more_then_100k']

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le_company = LabelEncoder()
le_job = LabelEncoder()
le_degree = LabelEncoder()

inputs['company_n'] = le_company.fit_transform(inputs['company'])
inputs['job_n'] = le_job.fit_transform(inputs['job'])
inputs['degree_n'] = le_degree.fit_transform(inputs['degree'])

inputs_n = inputs.drop(['company','job','degree'],axis='columns')

from sklearn import tree
model = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(inputs_n, target)

model.score(inputs_n,target)
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057621/sklearn-labelencoder-with-never-seen-before-values) is your answer

Comment: thanks for that. I've tried as per your suggestion by using the code ```new_list = ['google']
print(le_company.fit_transform(new_list))``` and I've tested for google where it is displaying output ```[0]``` but it has to be ```[2]```

Comment: You should use `le_company.transform(new_list)`

Comment: I've modified and is working when I pass **google** but when i pass **apple** it is saying ```y contains previously unseen labels: ['apple']```

Comment: Because encoder never has seen 'apple'. You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057621/sklearn-labelencoder-with-never-seen-before-values)

Comment: Got that. If i want to predict on new values how will i do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222116/discussion-between-vikas-and-vaziri-mahmoud).